# Capture MKMapView screenshot off screen

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview

I want to get a screenshot of a map view that is hidden from the user. 
So, i'm creating the map view and set it to be hidden, but then I don't get the delegate callbacks: `mapViewWillStartLoadingMap` and `mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap`.

How can I tell when the map was fully loaded to take the screenshot? Is there a better solution than what I'm trying to do?
Thanks,

Comment: What about dorking with the opacity? Those delegates may still get called if the opacity is set to 0....

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. I really want to get them callbacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, thank Google!
Instead of drawing a map view and try to make it hidden, then wait for the callbacks and capture the screen, I used Google maps API.
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=32.084684,34.888237&zoom=12&size=190x90&sensor=true.

Amazing :)